# How to override openFile() in ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I created an app for Android. The app stores/displays data the user inputs. I'm using a database for the storage.

I'm also providing a ContentProvider so other applications can access the data. All methods for my ContentProvider work except the openFile() method. I want to provide a file through that method which holds the stored data in a plaintext format.

I don't know how I should override the openFile method for this to work. What I was planning to do is create the file in that method, fill it with the data from the database and return a ParcelFileDescriptor with a reference to that file.

Is this the right approach? If yes, can you provide sample code?
If not, how should I approach this (with sample code)?

Answer (score 0):

From the Problem statement what i could understand is, the problem is not with opening of file, its the openfile which is not getting over ride.

Openfile ()  --> is not invoked inspite of doing all required stuffs for content provider... Even i am facing this problem.

Best Regards
Vinod